# How to make a page scrollable when a div(position: fixed) goes out of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this code, there are two divs(div1 and div2), Div2 is synchronized with div1, which means when we scroll div1, the div2 is also moving. I want to make the page scrollable when the div2 goes out of the page, so we can see the div2. Without changing position of div2 **Run snippet in full-page**

```js
 var main = document.querySelector('.div1');
        var target = document.querySelector('.div2');
        var target_offsetTop = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        main.onscroll = function () {
            var main_scrollStart = main.scrollTop;
            var targetCurrentTop = target_offsetTop + main_scrollStart;
            target.style.top = targetCurrentTop + 'px';
        }
```

```css
.div1 {
   background-color: blue;
   width: 100px;
   height: 300px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   position: fixed;   
}

.div2 {
   background-color: red;
   width: 100px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 600px;
   left: 130px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="div1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the position of div2 'relative'

```js
        var main = document.querySelector('.div1');
        var target = document.querySelector('.div2');
        var target_offsetTop = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        main.onscroll = function() {
            var main_scrollStart = main.scrollTop;
            var targetCurrentTop = target_offsetTop + main_scrollStart;
            target.style.top = targetCurrentTop + 'px';
        }
```

```css
        .div1 {
            background-color: blue;
            width: 100px;
            height: 300px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            position: fixed;
        }
        
        .div2 {
            background-color: red;
            width: 100px;
            position: relative;
            top: 590px;
            left: 130px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="div1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
```

Comment: No, I don't want to change the position of div2 because It affects a lot in my origin application.